# Use a Drop Down Menu to Query A Database and Return the Results Without Leaving The Page

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html

I have a page with some PHP that looks like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="wheniwant">Date</th>
            <th class="wheniwant">Income Amount</th>
            <th class="wheniwant">Expense Amount</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <?php
    //DB CONNECTION

    $varDatePaid = ""; $varIncomePaid =""; $varExpensePaid = "";

    $sql = mysql_query( 
        "
            SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`date_paid`, '%Y-%m') `date_paid`,
            SUM(CASE WHEN `categoryType` = 'Income' THEN `amount_paid` END) `IncomeAmount`,
            SUM(CASE WHEN `categoryType` = 'Expense' THEN `amount_paid` END) `ExpenseAmount`
            FROM `accounting`
            GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`date_paid`, '%Y-%m')
        "
     );


    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
        {
            $varDatePaid = $row['date_paid'];
            $varIncomePaid = $row['IncomeAmount'];
            $varExpensePaid = $row['ExpenseAmount'];                        
    ?>


    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $varDatePaid; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $varIncomePaid; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $varExpensePaid; ?></td>
        </tr>

    <?php   

        }
    ?>
</table>
```

This returns a table like:

[image: Screenshot]

I want to then add something:

```
$sql_query = "SELECT id, DATE_FORMAT(`date_paid`, '%Y') AS year FROM accounting GROUP BY year ORDER BY year DESC";


$result = mysql_query($sql_query) or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo '<option value='. $row['year'] . '>'. $row['year'] . '</option>';
```

To create some sort of filter to limit the result to a particular year. How do I do this without leaving the page?

Comment: I guess you're looking for an AJAX solution. You cant rerun a PHP script after loading the page, hovever its fully possible to have a javascript/jQuery to load contents from an external PHP script into your page without reloading it.

Comment: I'd recommend looking into http://datatables.net/

Comment: I understand that fact. Can you show me how it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so you are going to want to read up on AJAX over [here](http://w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp). It's not very difficult and for the most part you can copy the code right off of that site. Alternatively depending on how much data you have and if you don't really want to learn something new, you could load the entire data set on page load and then use JS to just pick out the parts you want once they fill out the form. I would suggest the AJAX route.

Someone else mentioned something about external PHP scripts which I guess is possible but I'm not sure how that would work. I would assume that you have to use JS on your first page to make a cookie that says what you want, then you open a new tab or window where you perform your query and store the value as a cookie or session variable, then use JS to close that window when the query is done, and then use JS again to put the results of the query back onto the page. I suppose that would work but it seems like not the most efficient way to go about this.